# How to estimate a server specifications for this particular system?

Tags: hardware, users, specifications

I'm working in a college project and I'm supposed to specify the server's hardware to hold a system. The system is some kind of social network. And it is supposed to hold around 100 000 users the first year, also the system must be able to handle 1000 users working at the same time. It is the first time I'm asked to do something like this, so I hope you can give me a hand and help me because I feel a little lost. The system's data base is Mysql.
I found some server configurations offered by Amazon Web Services, but I don't know which of them is the better for my system due to lack of experience
Hope you can help me.

Comment: You may wish to read our canonical question on capacity planning at http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning .

Comment: I wont like that one closed - this is not so much a "shopping" question as a "how do I analyze this", which is valid. Not everone knows how to analzye a cloud setup. Read my answer how I do not give specific advice but still answer the question.

Comment: It wasn't closed as a shopping question, it was closed because the author is patently not a professional sysadmin, and is not doing this as part of his or her professional life.  Moreover, if it hadn't been widely thought of as off-topic for the reason given, I would have voted to close it as a duplicate of the canonical question above.  But don't let me stop you from nominating it for reopening - that's how the system is supposed to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically do not. Seriously. THis is not a "size the server" question. 100.000 users is at or closo to server farm material, so - plan accordingly. Go for servers in the financial sweet spot (at a certai nstage they get more expensive per unit) and plan for a cluster front and back end.

1000 concurrent users you do not want to run with one server - even if capacity holds, you are too vulnerable. That is a minimum of 2, better 4 machienes (splitting front and back). You can use a cloud to start without buying hardware but you MUST build for scalability right from the start. Stuff like Amazon.

Which means sizing a single server is something not needed. You can adjust.

Comment: since looks like they will close the topic soon, I give you the points. Thanks for the help I will take a different approach now